# The clear meaning of the decorator @Injectable in Angular 5+

Tags: angular

As far as I know, a class can get dependencies injected from the Angular injector with a decorator such as `@Injectable`, `@Component`.

So I consider `@Injectable` decorator as some sort of a "badge", telling Angular that "I(class) allow you to inject dependencies I request" and I believe this is correct.

But this sentence from the official document confuses me:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserContextService {}
```

> The @Injectable decorator indicates that the Angular DI system is used to create one or more instances of UserContextService.

In my knowledge, `@Injectable` decorator has nothing to do with the injector creating an instance of the class.

Am I missing something?

P.S. [The official document link for the sentence above](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the documentation is wrong on this one. `@Injectable` actually means "I(service) can have other services injected into me". Consider this service called `Service2` that attempts to have `Service1` injected in the constructor:

```
// If you remove this, you will get an error
@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  constructor(private service: Service1) { 

  }
}
```

As noted by the comment, removing `@Injectable()` causes this to throw an error. You can try it using a [StackBlitz I created](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2sc6n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice2.service.ts). Components don't need `@Injectable()` to have services injected in them though.

I found [an issue where this was discussed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12098) but nothing seemed to ever come from it. To think, I took the documentation at face value and have been using `@Injectable()` incorrectly this entire time. Thank you for this question.

This prompted me to dig even deeper and look at the test referenced by the documents. It fails, but not for the reason the documentation says it fails. And they actually have a test to verify you **can** inject a service that **does not** have the decorator. I wrote up more information for the curious [here](http://www.deanpdx.com/2018/07/30/what-does-angular-injectable-mean.html).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Angular injector is perfectly able to inject a instance of a class without the `@Injectable` decorator. Angular throws an error WHEN a class requests an dependency without the decorator.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/injectable-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
I've written a test about this. As you can see, `Test1Service` has no `@Injectable` decorator but the injector of `AppComponent` perfectly injects an instance of it without any issue.

Comment: Hey @DongBinKim after reading your comment, I wrote the same exact test app and came to the same conclusion and found an answer. The documentation is wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Glad to discuss it :D Thank you!